# white screen google sign-in popup issue only appearing in mobile browser

Tags: vuejs2, google-signin

I have been playing with the google sign in. I have found that it works well with desktop browsers, but on mobile phone an empty white screen opens instead of pop up and there are no options to select anything.

```
<template>
  <div ref="googleLoginBtn" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    const gClientId =[XXXCLIENTID];

    window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: gClientId,
      callback: this.handleCredentialResponse,
      auto_select: true,
    });

    window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(this.$refs.googleLoginBtn, {
      text: "signin_with",
      size: "large",
      width: "366",
      theme: "outline",
      logo_alignment: "left",
    });
  },
  methods: {
    async handleCredentialResponse(response) {
      console.log(response.credential);
      // Put your backend code in here
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

EDIT 1: clearing browser cookies and history seemed to do the trick, but is this caused by my code or some other websites that I logged on?